# Android memory stat

Tags: android, memory-management

I use the following code to get the memory usage.

```
double allocated = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / (double) 1048576;
double available = Debug.getNativeHeapSize() / (double) 1048576.0;
double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize()) / (double) 1048576.0;
```

And I get the following log:

```
07-15 12:59:11.149: DEBUG/NKHeap(9363): debug.heap native: allocated 13,220MB of 16,059MB (0,108MB free)
```

My problem is that the free plus the allocated don't add up to the total. 
Am I missing something basic, or the is the precision I should expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the memory usage try something like:

```
Debug.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

String memMessage = String.format("Memory: Pss=%.2f MB,
Private=%.2f MB, Shared=%.2f MB",
memoryInfo.getTotalPss() / 1024.0,
memoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() / 1024.0,
memoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() / 1024.0);
```

You can read more about it in this blog [here.](http://huenlil.pixnet.net/blog/post/26872625)

Comment: However the code you wrote don't have the details I wanted, the link clearly explain why this is quite hard to achieve.